# MediaPlayer throwing errors in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've written a media app that streams MP3s using an HTTP connection. This has been working great on Android versions 2.x - 4.x but is now generating errors in 5.x. The app cycles through a playlist object containing MP3s, each having its own unique HTTP address. The first file streams fine, but the next file (doesn't matter *which* file) produces the following errors when `prepareAsync()` is called:

```
07-04 18:57:19.785     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 10 retries left
07-04 18:57:22.874     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 9 retries left
07-04 18:57:25.907     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 8 retries left
07-04 18:57:28.929     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 7 retries left
07-04 18:57:31.972     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 6 retries left
07-04 18:57:35.024     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 5 retries left
07-04 18:57:38.062     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 4 retries left
07-04 18:57:41.085     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 3 retries left
07-04 18:57:44.110     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 2 retries left
07-04 18:57:47.262     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 1 retries left
07-04 18:57:50.294     65-10860/? E/NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 0 retries left
07-04 18:57:50.419     65-10857/? E/GenericSource﹕ Failed to init from data source!
07-04 18:57:50.428    9592-9758/net.kicksass.shootingstarbbs.streamstar E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
07-04 18:57:50.429    9592-9592/net.kicksass.shootingstarbbs.streamstar E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

In general, the app calls MediaPlayer's `setDataSource(url)` followed by `prepareAsync()`, then waits for the `onPreparedListener` to fire after which `start()` is called to begin streaming. Upon streaming completion, it calls `reset()` and then `setDataSource(url)` where the process begins again.

Why is Lollipop's MediaPlayer throwing this error?

Comment: It would be a lot of code to post since there are listeners involved, methods being called, etc. I've tried to summarize what MediaPlayer methods I'm calling, in the order they're being called. I'm hoping someone else has seen these errors and found a solution, otherwise I'll have to start experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `setDataSource(string)` method used to automatically encode a passed-in URL with previous versions of Android but no longer in v5.x. The errors were occurring because the web server was returning an HTTP 404 Not Found. When I encode the URL before passing it to `setDataSource()` it works.

To further confuse things, my app was inconsistently encoding the URL, so sometimes it worked and other times it did not.

Comment: How did you encode it. I have this simple URL 
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Does this need to be encoded?

Comment: @Diffy I basically used `String encodedPath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8")` to encode, and then had to change some of the percent encodings back to ASCII. For example, `encodedPath = encodedPath.replace("%2F", "/")`. I also did this for spaces and plus signs (not an all-inclusive list of troublesome characters.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on lollipop as well. Spaces in the URL were causing this issue for me. I replaced the spaces with %20 and it works fine.

```html
used to be: mPlayer.setDataSource(myUrl);
changed to: mPlayer.setDataSource(myUrl.replaceAll(" ","%20"));
```

Hope this helps for the once having this issue as well. The Encode trick didn't work for me but put me on the right track in solving this for me.